# Groovy Httpbuilder authentication with Realm + RABBIT MQ

Tags: grails, groovy, rabbitmq, httpbuilder

I am trying to to make a rabbitmq http api call to know how queues are there and other infos...

I need 3 variables to pass on to the api

1) url: (http://localhost:55672/api) 2) username/password: guest/guest
    3) realm: "RabbitMQ Management" //i am not sure if this is important
    4) path: "/queues"

when i make curl statement it gives a positive response

`sudo curl -i -u guest:guest (http://localhost:55672)/api/queues
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: MochiWeb/1.1 WebMachine/1.7 (participate in the frantic)
Date: Tue, 03 Jul 2012 01:39:05 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 6176
Cache-Control: no-cache`

but using httpbuilder from groovy. here is the code

```
    def http = new HTTPBuilder("(http://localhost:55672/api)")
    http.auth.basic 'guest','guest'

    http.request(GET) { req ->
        uri.path = '/queues'

        response.success = { resp, reader ->
            assert resp.statusLine.statusCode == 200
            println "Got response: ${resp.statusLine}"
            println "Content-Type: ${resp.headers.'Content-Type'}"
            println reader.json
        }

        response.'404' = { println 'Not found' }
    }
```

I am getting "not found" as the result. I am not including realm because I am unable to if i can insert  "realm" in httpbuilder. it only comes with OAuth however I need to use basic auth for rabbit mq http api calls.

Does anyone knows how to include realm name in httpbuilder groovy for basic authentication? is there any other way. Kindly let me know! thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder( 'http://localhost:55672' )
http.auth.basic 'guest','guest'
http.request(GET) { req ->
    uri.path = '/api/queues'
    response.success = { resp, reader ->
        assert resp.statusLine.statusCode == 200
        println "Got response: ${resp.statusLine}"
        println "Content-Type: ${resp.headers.'Content-Type'}"
        println reader.json
    }
    response.'404' = { println 'Not found' }
}
```

Took the braces and the path out of your base url, added `/api` to the path